# Making a menu in json

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to display json into a bootstrap menu.  But I don't know how to do it. I would like to do this with jquery but mybe an only javascript code is more simple.  I tried like this. I used jquery library.

thanks for your help

```js
{
  "refs":
    [
        {
          "category" : "webdev",
          "title" : "Référence CSS : Codrops",
          "description" : "LA référence CSS à avoir dans ses bookmarks : complète et très didactique. Avec notamment une très bonne introduction à Flexbox ",
          "link" : "http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/flexbox/",
          "miniature" : "http://codropspz.tympanus.netdna-cdn.com/codrops/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/cssrefmain.jpg"
        },
        {
          "category" : "webdesign",
          "title" : "A second link to try",
          "description" : "Obviously, this is a really intersting link",
          "link" : "the link",
          "miniature" : "http://codropspz.tympanus.netdna-cdn.com/codrops/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/cssrefmain.jpg"
        },
        {
          "category" : "webdev",
          "title" : "A third link to try",
          "description" : "Obviously, this is a really intersting link",
          "link" : "the link",
          "miniature" : "http://codropspz.tympanus.netdna-cdn.com/codrops/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/cssrefmain.jpg"
        },
        {
          "category" : "divers",
          "title" : "A fourth link to try",
          "description" : "Obviously, this is a really intersting link",
          "link" : "the link",
          "miniature" : "http://codropspz.tympanus.netdna-cdn.com/codrops/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/cssrefmain.jpg"
        },
        {
          "category" : "webdev",
          "title" : "Javascript ",
          "description" : "Obviously, this is a really intersting link",
          "link" : "http://www.w3.org/wiki/JavaScript_best_practices",
          "miniature" : "http://codropspz.tympanus.netdna-cdn.com/codrops/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/cssrefmain.jpg"
        }

      ]
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>Loïc did it</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<script type="text/javascript">

    

 $.getJSON("references.json",
        function (json) {
            var ul;
        li = $('</ul>');
        li.append("<li> " + json.category + "</li>")
        $('#menu').append(ul);
        });


</script>

</head>


<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Vidéos</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="menu">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">accueil</a></li>
                

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look carefully at your variable names...

Comment: thanks but I look at this and find nothing.

Comment: Well it's not like there are a lot of lines in there so the mistake should be easy to find. Also one should "always" use [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) which would also have made the mistake clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Loïc did it</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.getJSON("references.json",
                   function (json) {
                       var li = '';
                       $.each(json.refs, function (index, responce) {
                           var cls = (index == 0 ? "active" : "");
                           li += "<ul class=\"nav navbar-nav\" ><li class=\"" + cls + "\"><a > " + $(this)[0].category + "</a></li></ul>";
                       });
                       $('#menu').html(li);
                   });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Vidéos</a>
            </div>
            <div id="menu">
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

your array of category items are inside refs jobject you have loop through array and get category names

```
$.each(jsondata.refs, function(i, d) {
  console.log(d.category)
  $("#menu").append("<li>" + d.category + "</li>")
});
```

Here's link https://jsfiddle.net/4196np59/